# Couldn't recognize database Variables

Tags: sql, database, flutter, android-studio, dart

I'm trying to make a to do app lists of information which get data from the base..
while I'm creating db_provider.dart file:

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

class DBProvider {
  DBProvider._();
  static final DBProvider dataBase = DBProvider._();
  static Database _database; //here the Problem showed
```

[a Picture which shows the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTEom.png)

Answer (score 0):

you added an `_` to the `_database` variable, this makes it private and not visible outside this class, remove the `_` to accomplish what you are trying to do.

https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#libraries-and-visibility

Comment: thanks for helping@csas
but it still shows an error
[this is a picture which shows the Error](https://github.com/zieadshabkalieh/ToDoApp/blob/main/Untitled.png)